# Is it possible to detect when a device has been MAC filtered on a twitter's API account Without initiating a Block through Twitter?

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to detect when a device has been MAC filtered on Twitter's API account without initiating a block through Twitter?

The reason I say this is some politicians on Twitter seem to have a way now of limiting certain people who criticize them without blocking them.

Comment: welcome - please edit your q to specify what you mean by "MAC filtered" .. there could be any number of technical (or sociological) reasons why Some Politician ignores Another Person (choice or ignorance)

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking; the question seems to be some buzzwords without any relation. MAC Filter? Twitter's API Account? Block? Please explain what you're talking about in some more detail.

Comment: Once you define the terms you use, this should be asked on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/